# import excel data to sql server database table and display in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, excel, gridview

How to import excel data to sql server database table and display in gridview in asp.net . I have done the binding part and i dont know how to import excel data.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=studentdetails;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Table Name",con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource=rdr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Management Studio Import Wizard to import excel to a table in database.
[See here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm).